# Tag description in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

When searching a tag in the respective tab, there should be a little frame with the tag's description (perhaps just a the first two lines and a 'Read more' button).

Currently the user is forced to guess what the tag stands for which is a little confusing for a tag like 'processing' etc..

[image: Current tag search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching for tags now, a "Tag Info" button will appear under the cancel button. Tapping it will take you to a tag description page with the tag's wiki info.

[image]

Comment: That does solve the issue I have - if I am reading a question in the detail view I cannot see the the tag info link button. A tooltip showing the tag description would be very helpful.