# Long press to show tag info in app

Tags: feature-request, tags, ios-app

Can we get a menu after long-pressing a tag anywhere throughout the app?

> [image]

This gives the user access to many of the same options provided by the information bar at the top of a tag search in desktop:

> [image]

In my mockup I omitted **synonyms** (it seemed mostly irrelevant) and **improve tag wiki** (broken for most users as suggested edits don't work in the api), but those could be added too.

Places this menu would be shown:

- Tags tab
- Tag search (Maybe with a little `(i)` button...uh, somewhere). [Another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230094/tag-description-in-ios-app) posted something similar for this
- Question post
- Ask Question dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have added this feature in our Beta App, it should be available in **Beta version 1.0.1.73**.

We found the long-press just a tad bit undiscoverable for many users, especially for something like a table cell.

So, instead, when you tap or search for a single tag, you should see a small button on the header that says **"About this tag"**:

[image: The About This Tag Button screenshot]

Tapping on that will lead you to the tag info screen:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It's apparently even already released! (Are update notifications fixed yet?)